# Call view from a stored procedure based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, view

I have a datatable like, as below. I have created a multiple views with different logic based on ID numbers.

Can anyone please tell me: is it possible to have a stored procedure which will execute a view **based on the id** available in table?

In this example: ID 1001 has a different view, and ID 1002 have yet another.

The table will have data for a **specific** ID at a **given point of time**.
and **will get truncated** before loading data with different ID.

DDL:

```
declare @table table
(
id int,
sales numeric (10,2),
years date
)

insert @table

select 1001 , 25000,'2005-05-01' union all
select 1001,256565,'2006-10-01' union all
select 1002 , 55000,'2005-10-11' union all
select 1002,56565,'2006-11-21 '
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some sample logic behind views creation for each id ?

Comment: Why are you creating separate views for each id??? You should create a view and then use a where clause. Or maybe a stored procedure that receives id as a parameter?

Comment: You cannot **execute** a view - you can **select** from it, though ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need something like this?:

```
If @id = 1001 
SELECT * FROM VIEW_1
If @id = 1002
SELECT * FROM VIEW_2
```